# How to select p terms with powers larger than 1 in a given expression?

Tags: filtering

My expression is:

```
expr = (p^(1/3) q + 5)/(3q^2)+p^2+(p-1)^(1/3)
```

And I want to single out all terms with $p^k, k > 1$

How should I do that? (If there is any way other than applying Series[] would be the best, since I want it to be less time-consuming when dealing with large expr.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Please give your expression in code. This will make it easier for others to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I want to single out all terms with p^k,k>1

I use this nice function `getPatterns` thanks to Carl Woll that he gave me as an answer long time ago.  It is a handy function to have in your toolbox.

```
ClearAll[p, q];
expr=(p^(1/3)*q+5)/(3*q^2)+p^2+(p-1)^(1/3)+p^5+(p^(9/2)-1)^(1/3)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := Last@Reap[expr /. a : pat :> Sow[a], _, Sequence @@ #2 &];
```

And now

```
getPatterns[expr, Power[p, x_] /; x > 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

replying to comment

> if there is a term 2 q p^(1/3), it only gives p^(1/3) while neglecting
> 2 q factor in front under current setting. And I want to have the
> final answers attached with 2 q factor

You can change the pattern to

```
expr = (2 *q*p^(1/3)*q + 5)/(3*q^2) + p^2 + (p - 1)^(1/3) + 
  p^5 + (888*p^(1/2) - 1)^(1/3)
getPatterns[expr, any_*Power[p, x_] /; x < 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But is there anyway to also single out the coefficients corresponding to the terms?

Comment: @TianyiWang You mean the actual powers themselves?

Comment: For example, if there is a term 2 q p^(1/3), it only gives p^(1/3) while neglecting 2 q factor in front under current setting. And I want to have the final answers attached with 2 q factor.

Comment: @TianyiWang  please see edit.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot!